# Memory Management with C++ Linked List Template Class

Tags: c++, linked-list

So, I've written a linked list class once before, but now I need to write a Linked List Template class. Not a big deal, but I've been having issues with the delete operator big time.
I reused as much code as possible, but I can't figure out why my functions to remove nodes don't behave the same in both programs. In my template class implementation I get run time errors when trying to free the memory with delete.

Here's the relevant code:

All nodes are added in main.cpp via the following function:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
    if( pHead == NULL )
    {
        pHead = new LinkedList<T>( data );
    }
    else
    {
        LinkedList<T> *ptr = pHead;
        while( ptr->pNext != NULL )
        {
            ptr = ptr->pNext;
        }
        ptr->pNext = new LinkedList<T>( data );
    }
}
```

All nodes are removed in main.cpp via the following function:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeFirst()
{
    if( !pHead ) return;
    else
    {
        LinkedList<T> *next = pHead;
        pHead = pHead->pNext;
        if( next != NULL)
        {
            delete next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my destructor code:

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    clear();
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
    LinkedList<T> *ptr = pHead;
    while( ptr )
    {
        LinkedList<T> *pTemp = ptr->pNext;
        delete ptr;
        ptr = pTemp;
    }
    pHead = NULL;
}
```

I get an access violation at the point where the removeFirst function tries to call delete.
I feel like the issue is simple, but almost exactly the same code worked in my non-template implementation so I wanted to see what others think before I bang my head against the wall too long.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the declaration of `LinkedList`?

Comment: Not the problem, but I find no reason for `if( next != NULL)` in the `reomveFirst` function since you have already checked `pHead` and assigned it to `next`.

Comment: The problem can be solved (or at least isolated) by stepping through the code in the debugger.

Comment: Can you try to launch it in debug mode and get the exact line where you get the error?

Comment: He already mentioned that: "at the point where the removeFirst function tries to call delete."

Comment: Show us the constructor called when  `new LinkedList<T>( data );`, I think the problem is that you are not assigning `NULL` to the new node's `pNext` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think clearly about the following three functions and decide whether they should remove just one item, or should clear the whole list:

```
removeFirst
clear
~LinkedList
```

As it stands, all these functions attempt to clear the whole list. The crash happens because the code in `clear` attempts to delete the same things multiple times.

I'm sorry to say that your code is badly flawed in many ways. You probably want the following:

```
~LinkedList() // delete *just this one node*, leaving the rest intact
clear()       // scan through the list. deleting each node (individually) in turn
removeFirst   // delete just one node.
```

Every call to `delete` leads to a call to `~LinkedList` which, currently, then attempts to clear the whole list.

Comment: That would be the issue indeed. Now, here's a question: I simply made the constructor empty, because it wouldn't compile if I let it use the default constructor that the compiler provides. Is that an okay practice? Or a bad habit I should kick?

Comment: I don't think I believe this: *"I simply made the constructor empty, because it wouldn't compile if I let it use the default constructor that the compiler provides."* You'll need to show us all the relevant code. What error did it give?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess without seeing the rest of the code, ie the constructor or your use of pHead except in the first node.

You're calling delete on next which calls ~LinkedList which will in its turn call clear().

Clear will use pHead of the node you're removing which makes no real sense since it's not the first node, and I suspect it's not initialized.

*kaboom*

I would recommend making a separate class for the actual LinkedList, with the add/remove methods, and the nodes in the list (LinkedListNode?) that only need a pNext pointer. Having pHead in the content nodes without it being used there confuses the issue somewhat :)